# Swift 4 accessing completionhandler returned value from class variable

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, swift4, completionhandler

Problem: I’m trying to access the value which is returned from completionHandler, to assign it to a variable which is outside the scope of completionHandler returned method. I can access the variable in the scope of the method, but I can’t from outside. I’ve tried to assign it to the class variable when I access, but didn’t work. Any ideas?

```
var marketler = [MarketModel]()
var marketAdiArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    getMarkets { (marketdizi) in
        self.objAryToTableView(markets: marketdizi)
        print(self.marketAdiArray) // -> this returns the right array
    }

    print(self.marketAdiArray) // -> this returns an empty array
 }

func getMarkets(completionHandler : @escaping ([MarketModel])->()) {
    let uid = "userID(02)"
    print("uid : \(uid)")
    MobileUserViewModel().getUser(userId: uid, completionHandler: { (user) in
// here returns an user object
        self.loginUser = user
        MarketViewModel().getMarketFromDb(mobilUser: user, completionHandler: { (marketler) in
            print("marketler : \(marketler)")
            completionHandler(marketler)
        })
    })
}

 func objAryToTableView(markets : [MarketModel]) {
    var ary = [String]()
    for m in markets {
        ary.append(m.marketName as String!)
    }
    self.marketAdiArray = ary
}
```

Comment: The `print` within the completion handler provided to `getMarkets` works properly because it's invoked when the `getMarketFromDb` call succeeds. The `print` after that closure doesn't work as you expected, because it's called immediately after the previous line, without waiting for  `getMarketFromDb` to complete.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and is there a way to assign the value to another variable in class ? Or any other advice ?

Comment: The assignment isn't the issue. The issue is that you're accessing the variable prior it's ready (before the async call to `getMarketFromDb`).

Answer (score 2):

The code inside the block (completion handler) is getting executed after `getMarketFromDb` call succeeds. The code which is outside the block is executed just after the previous line where you don't have any data on the array.

If You need to trigger the UI update which updated data from data Db then you need to invoke the UI update from inside the completion block.

```
getMarkets { (marketdizi) in

         self.objAryToTableView(markets: marketdizi)
         print(self.marketAdiArray) // -> this returns the right array
         self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
    print(self.marketAdiArray) // -> this returns an empty array
```